# WinForms RabbitMQ Encoding not working properly

Tags: c#, encoding, rabbitmq, .net-6.0

I'm making an application which receives RabbitMQ messages from a queue, but the encoding is not working properly.

This is what my the message (JSON format) looks like:

```
{
    "deviceId": 1234,
    "message": "{\"message\":\"This is a message\"}",
    "sentEpoch": 12345,
    "type": "UPDATE"
}
```

This is the code that handles receiving a message:

```
consumer.Received += async (model, ea) =>
            {
                var receivedEpoch = await _epochService.GetEpochFromAPI();
                var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
            };
```

This is just like it is used in the [RabbitMQ tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-dotnet.htm).

Now the actual problem. When I add a message to the queue and I start the application after, `message` will be as expected:

```
{
    "deviceId": 1234,
    "message": "{\"message\":\"This is a message\"}",
    "sentEpoch": 12345,
    "type": "UPDATE"
}
```

But when I add a message to the queue while the WinForms application is already running, it sometimes (I can't seem to find a pattern) has a string like this instead of the expected JSON when decoding:

```
"\u0017\u0003\u0003\0{\0\0\0\0\0\0\0D�\u0383,�*J���ߟ��<�9�˪b5\u0001Ռ\u0016\u001d�ѷ\u0004\u0018��]y�\u0004T̛x��Ȁ_\u0018�\u0010�\u001e(�n�ל\u0012�/z;\u007f��aP=��\t\u0010.�ǲ���`��6�6XC�\u0018��Q,<HB�\u000e��v�\tH>�Ȅ���\u0012\u0001�DATE\"}"
```

So obviously I can't deserialize that string. But the weird thing is, when I restart my WinForms application and listen for new messages, the same message as above decodes to the expected JSON.

I really can't put a finger on the problem and hope someone can point me in the right direction. If you need more info let me know!

### Update

Now I've tried to post the messages directly within the management dashboard of RabbitMQ. Still the same result.

I also tried to put a while loop around the encoding, just to check if the same message would encode to the same string everytime, which it does. So I'm starting to suspect a bug in RabbitMQ.

I'm using quorum queues on 3 nodes in combination with persistent messages and durable queues.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it works like this, but it has something to do with the

`var receivedEpoch = await _epochService.GetEpochFromAPI();`

If I change my code to

```
consumer.Received += async (model, ea) =>
            {
                var receivedEpoch = _epochService.GetEpochFromAPI();
                var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                receivedEpoch = await receivedEpoch;
            };
```

It doesn't show the weird message anymore and everything works as expected. If someone knows why it works like this, let me know.